# How can I reference a JSON source for a derived column action in Azure Data Factory

Tags: json, azure, azure-data-factory

I'm new to Azure Data Factory. I've been able to generate a set of JSON files from a REST API source using a Pipeline. Each file consists of one top level JSON object with an array of up to 100 child objects. The output is saved to an Azure Blob Storage container.

I now want to use a Mapping Data Flow to modify the JSON before I write it to Azure SQL, however I'm struggling with the syntax. I've configured the source to point to the directory containing the JSON files. The Source Projection tab displays the correct schema. I can preview the data and I see a row for each file and I can expand the child objects to see the full structure.

However, when I add a Derived Column action, the Input Schema is blank in the Expression Builder. I can refer to the top level elements in the source using the byName and byPosition functions, but I don't know how I can reference the child elements.

The examples that I have been able to find online use a SQL table or CSV file as a source. I can't find any examples that use hierarchical data as the source for a derived column.

Am I missing something? Is this scenario supported?

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to achieve what I want. This may not be the best approach, but it works.

It seems that it is difficult to deal with JSON that has multiple hierarchies as a source for copy data activities. You can choose one level of repeating data to map to a table structure (the Collection Reference property on the Mapping tab).

In my scenario, there was additional repeating data within the data I was mapping to my table. I updated the mapping to write the child JSON data to a text field in my SQL table. To do this, I needed to use the Azure Data Factory JSON editor for my pipeline. You can access this from the "Code" link in the top right corner of the pipeline visual editor.

I added the following line after the closing bracket for the "mappings" array for my copy activity:
"mapComplexValuesToString": true

The full path to the mapping array in the activity definition is typeProperties - translator - mappings. Make sure your commas are correct after you add the new element.

With this approach, I had a row in my SQL table for each array item in my Collection Reference. The scalar child elements in the array items are mapped to table columns and the child JSON element is written to a data column in the same table.

To extract the values I need within the child JSON, I created a SQL view that uses the CROSS APPLY OPENJSON syntax. This allows me to treat the JSON in the data field similar to a related table. You can specify the structure that your JSON is in. If you have nested data in your JSON, you can apply the same approach for each level.

The OPENJSON command is only supported by more recent versions of SQL Server. I'm using Azure SQL, so that works for me.